# "log in using facebook" implementation using casperjs

Tags: javascript, facebook, node.js, web, casperjs

I saw a lot of sites that have the option to log in using `Facebook` (airbnb, about.me, etc).

I want to implement automated log in to those sites (to scrape them latter) using a Facebook account.

this the code for `about.me`:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

var fbUsername = casper.cli.args[0]
var fbPassword = casper.cli.args[1]

// login to facebook
casper.start('https://www.facebook.com/login.php?', function() 
{   
    this.fill('form#login_form', 
    {
       'email': fbUsername,
       'pass': fbPassword,
    },true)
});

casper.thenOpen("https://about.me/login",function() 
{
    this.waitForSelector('#facebook_login',function()
    {
       this.click('#facebook_login')    
    })
});

casper.thenOpen("https://about.me/account/#!/myinformation",function()
{
    this.debugHTML()
})

casper.run();
```

I see that I do signing in to Facebook, but for every site that I tried, I can't log in to it, because the press on the "facebook login" is not working (every time).

can anyone help me to understand where is the problem and how can I solve it?